# IE8 SSL Cert Problems while other browsers work like a charm

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-8, certificate

I bought a SSL Cert which should work with iE 5+, but it doesn`t. All other browsers i tested work perfectly - no errors - just the site I want to display. But IE8 and smaller versions show an Error on the https...(they need to accept the ssl cert) site and destroy the layout on http version of the site (no https links included).

Non SSL
minol-fb.de/facebook-suche/

SSL
minol-fb.de/facebook-suche/

Ok it seems that browser < IE8 still use the self signed certificate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have configured multiple certificates [using Server Name Indication](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) without knowing it.

If you use this, you get a self-signed certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.minol-fb.de:443
```

If you use this (with the server name), you get the correct certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.minol-fb.de:443 -servername www.minol-fb.de
```

You probably get a different behaviour with older versions of IE because you're testing them on XP. No version of IE supports SNI on Windows XP unfortunately. Other browsers (with sufficiently recent versions) do, at least independently on the OS version they run on.

If you don't need that other host, you can probably remove that configuration, so as not to have to rely on SNI at all.

Comment: Your answer helps understand me a problem. Then I found [this article](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.2.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=68308.htm) and solve the problem, thx.

Comment: Any thoughts on HOW to remove the self-signed cert in heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Something odd is going on; if you use the link below you will see that the server is not returning the server cert and intermediate cert, but a single self signed Parallels Plesk Panel CA cert.

http://certlogik.com/ssl-checker/www.minol-fb.de

Using the openssl command below, I get the same Plesk certificate returned:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.minol-fb.de:443
```

Perhaps this may help:

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/questions/457/Installing+a+SSL+Certificate+in+Plesk+9

**UPDATE:**

Looks like you've sorted out the config; using the above tool I can see the correct certs are now being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation where the cert was working OK on all browsers except for IE (of course!). This is on Apache and the SSL cert had been issued by RapidSSL. Turned out in my case, that I had virtual host file default-ssl active, so somehow IE was picking up on that on the default self-signed cert instead of the rapidSSL cert referred to in my site virtual host.

Deactivated ssl-default, reloaded apache and that did it.

Comment: How did you disable it? I can't find mention of default-ssl anywhere. I'm having this same issue, and having troubles resolving it.

Comment: @David to disable site run `sudo a2dissite default-ssl`