# SSL certificate error for IE users only

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

I recently migrated to a new server (CentOS with plesk 11.0) and installed a new SSL certificate for my domain.

Problem now is that any IE user has the error "there is a problem with this website's security certificate" when they try to access the secure area of my site.

I've tested all main configurations - MAC/Windows/mobile plus browsers: FF,Chrome,Safari,Opera,IE and the only combination that gives me this problem is IE on windows. IE 11 works fine, all previous versions (the majority) come up with this error.

where do I start?? I can find no problem with the installation and this is obviously denting confidence in my site.

Comment: Which authority signed your certificate?

Comment: Certificate is Starfield issued from Godaddy. Have tried all of the links posted but so far no luck.

Comment: Perhaps http://serverfault.com/a/476932

Comment: When it comes to IE problems the OS version is more important as the SSL lib is AFAIK part of the OS, not IE. Therefore what OS versions are affected?

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with IE and Certificates. Check these threads.

1) https://superuser.com/questions/379601/internet-explorer-refuses-to-connect-to-sites-with-untrusted-ssl-certificates

2) [IE8 SSL Cert Problems while other browsers work like a charm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906987/ie8-ssl-cert-problems-while-other-browsers-work-like-a-charm)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this issue. It is necessary to run https proxy which will accept certificate for Internet Explorer.  I use a Python HTTP/HTTPS Proxy [proxpy](https://code.google.com/p/proxpy/). You should point to required certificate file in core.py `DEFAULT_CERT_FILE = "./cert/ncerts/proxpy.pem"`. So you need to use proxy settings in Internet Explorer. It is 127.0.0.1:8080 for ProxyPy by default.