# Certificate error in Internet Explorer 8 in windows XP

Tags: azure, ssl, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

The project my teammates and I are working on is having security issues with internet explorer 8 running on windows xp.

Our app is hosted in a dedicated instance of Azure Websites, and has a EV certificate issued by GeoTrust. The certificate works correctly on all browsers, except Internet Explorer 8 running on windows xp. We get the following warning:

`The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.`

When I go to View certificates I only see the certificate issue to *.azurewebsites.net by `MSIT Machine Auth CS 2`.

We found more information about this issue on a previous question: [IE8 SSL Cert Problems while other browsers work like a charm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906987/ie8-ssl-cert-problems-while-other-browsers-work-like-a-charm)

And the solution is to remove the SNI configuration on IIS, but we can’t do that on azure websites. What can we do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you're sharing an external IP address (non dedicated azure websites?) and it's not working since  since IE8 on Windows XP does not support [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Browsers_with_support_for_TLS_server_name_indication.5B6.5D).

Getting a dedicated instance *should* solve your problem, although I've not tested whether a dedicated azure web site gets its unique IP or not so you may want to try it yourself.

Update: It would seem that you can [indeed choose not to use SNI](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl-web-site/) when uploading the certificate to a standard mode azure web site.

Comment: Joachim, I work with mamodom. We have a dedicated instance, and are aware of the SNI limitation with Windows XP.

We have two dedicated instances running our app, but since it's a website and not a cloud server, we can't go in and configure IIS

Comment: @amhed I see now that mamodom added some info on that after my answer. If you can't turn off SNI, there's currently no way that I'm aware of to make IE on XP work directly with your SSL server. One way forward that I can see is to proxy the request using [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) or similar running on one or more cloud servers. That way the dedicated server(s) can handle the SSL negotiations, the downside being that the SSL will not be end-to-end.

Comment: @amhed Found a page (linked in the answer) with info on uploading SSL certificates while selecting IP based SSL (ie non SNI). From my limited testing, when choosing IP based SSL it seems to not use SNI, although I don't have XP to test on.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case ... the SNI also seems to confuse the Android Bluefire Reader. We have a website that allows registered users to download bought ebooks and the direct download to Bluefire stopped working after the move to Azure. Once we chaged the setings of the certificates in Azure, both IE+WinXP and Blufire started working.